# how to predict a value after linear regression without knowing any information of future

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm a newbie of machine learning and I'm doing a project about predicting the sales volume of a company. I have the data of past few months and already trained a linear model(e.g. `h = θ0 + θ1*X1 + θ2*X2 + θ3*X3`). But I don't know how to predict the sales volume of next month without knowing anything (`X1,X2,X3`). Could you please tell me how to realize that?

Comment: I find it amusing that anyone would call linear regression "machine learning". Anyway, you can't predict without knowing the values of the predictors. Maybe you should use a time series model instead (ARIMA comes to mind).

Comment: @Roland I'd certainly call linear regression machine learning. It's one of the first topics in [Andrew Ng's ML class](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex2/ex2.html), for example.

Comment: @Nate customerType, sellerType, destination something like those, should I use general features?

Answer (score 2):

To use a regression model for forecasting, the X's (independent variables) have to be known or created based on assumptions.  If you do not know, or want to estimate, the X's, you should look at a time series based model such as Box Jenkins (a technique to apply an ARIMA model mentioned by @Roland).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Jenkins